# Print column2 from row with max(column1) without including column2 in group by clause

Tags: oracle, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

I know it is a silly question and may be already answered somewhere, please guide me to the link if it is.

I want to print a column which is not included in group by clause. Oracle says that it should be included in group by expression, but I want value to be from the same row from which max() value for the other column was selected.

For example: if I have a table with following columns:

> Employee_Name, Action_code, Action_Name

I want to see the name of action with maximum action_code for each employee, also I cannot use subquery in the condition.

I want some thing like this:

```
select employee_name, max(action_code), action_name --for max code
from emp_table
group by employee_name
```

This **action_name** in select statement is causing problem, if I add action_name in group by clause then it will show action name for each action for each employee, which will make the query meaningless.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`keep .. last` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST.html#):

```
select employee_name,
  max(action_code) as action_code,
  max(action_name) keep (dense_rank last order by action_code) as action_name
from emp_table
group by employee_name
```

The documentation explains this more fully under the sister function [`first()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html).